# http server not honoring Accept-Encoding: gzip unless User-Agent is known browser

Tags: android, http, gzip, user-agent

When making an HTTP request, I set `Accept-Encoding: gzip`.  However, I notice that the server doesn't actually compress the response unless `User-Agent` is "well-known".  I have the following Android code that demonstrates the problem, it gets "http://www.google.com" using my awesome user-agent, and checks if the response is compressed:

```
    HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpProtocolParams.setUserAgent(params, "MyApp/1.0 (Awesome)");

    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(params);       
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://www.google.com");
    request.setHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");

    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    Header header = entity.getContentEncoding();
    boolean isCompressed = false;
    if (header != null) {
        HeaderElement[] codecs = header.getElements();
        for (int i = 0; i < codecs.length; i++) {
            if (codecs[i].getName().equalsIgnoreCase("gzip")) {
                isCompressed = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (isCompressed)
        Log.i(TAG, "IT IS COMPRESSED");
    else
        Log.i(TAG, "IT IS NOT COMPRESSED");
```

Running this code prints out "IT IS NOT COMPRESSED"   :(

But if I set the user agent to `"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:6.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0"`, it outputs "IT IS COMPRESSED".

I know it is the server's choice whether to actually compress or not, but why is it choosing based on "User-Agent"?  Is there any other header options I should be sending to coax the server to compress, irrespective of the user-agent?

**EDIT:**

I know there's no proxy/etc along the way that is mangling the Accept-Encoding header, because when I get `http://1.cgi.browserscope.net/cgi-bin/resource.cgi?headers=1`, I see the Accept-Encoding header is received correctly

Comment: Out of interest, do you have the same problem with `Accept-Encoding: deflate`? And the obvious solution - albeit a work-around - is to just send a UA string for a well known browser...

Comment: @DaveRandom, when I use deflate, the response comes back uncompressed in both cases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's almost certainly doing this because some legacy User-Agents advertise support for GZIP and then fail to properly decompress the content. For that reason, some server-side frameworks are known to only send compressed responses to clients known not to suffer bugs like that.

Comment: I'd add that "legacy" in this case means "extremely old and very rarely seen." It's much less necessary to do this than it was five years ago.  Also, server-side frameworks that do this should send Vary: User-Agent or Vary: * on all responses.

Comment: Keeping in mind that the Vary: * will force the client to revalidate the response every time, which might be nearly as bad for performance...